# Appium test android device through Jenkins

Tags: android, selenium, jenkins, appium

I have set up jenkins, selenium grid, android sdk and appium.

I want to run my tests on a real device (Samsung). The device is connected via usb to my PC and developer mode is enabled.

```
adb devices
```

returns phone's id (or whatever that string is supposed to mean)

If i run my tests directly through appium everything works.

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
super.webDriverUrl = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
```

If i run another set of non-android tests using selenium grid also everything works as well.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(jenkinsurl+"/wd/hub",capabilities);
```

The problem is if i try to run android tests through selenium grid my setup wont work. Appium is starting with an argument `--nodeconfig /path/to/json`

In the json file are defined following capatibilities:

```
 "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName":"Android",
      "version":"4.2",
      "platformName":"Android",
      "deviceName":"4203abf3dab84100"
    }
  ],
```

appium output:

```
info: [debug] Appium successfully registered with the grid on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

The node is also diplayed in jenkins/selenium/

Following code is an example how do i create an instance of remotewebdriver

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName("Android");
capabilities.setCapability("Vesrion","4.2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","4203abf3dab84100");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(jenkinsurl+"/wd/hub",capabilities);
```

Console output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running somepackage.TestAndroid
Configuring TestNG with: TestNGMapConfigurator
```

And there it freezes, no exception in ide console,nor in appium process log. Samsung phone wont open chrome browser. I ran out of ideas, has anyone else faced similar problem?
Using Linux

Comment: I use - "browserName": "Chrome"